# In kubernetes, what happens if a namespace is created without limit-range?

Tags: kubernetes

I am struggling to figure out whether the namespace created without limit-range can resources use up to maximum possible leaving issues for other namespaces.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LimitRange provides constraints that can:

- Enforce minimum and maximum computing resources usage per Pod or Container in a namespace.
- Enforce minimum and maximum storage request per PersistentVolumeClaim in a namespace.
- Enforce a ratio between request and limit for a resource in a namespace.

So if a namespace is created without LimitRange there are no constraints and you can't enforce the use of minimum and maximum per Pod.

For more details, check the link:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/